# ERROR TS6054: File '~lib/@tensorflow/tfjs-node.ts' not found

Tags: tensorflow.js, assemblyscript

I'm trying to use AssemblyScript to build a WebAssembly inference engine for a TensorFlow.js model that I have.

I started with essentially the [quickstart AssemblyScript app](https://www.assemblyscript.org/quick-start.html) (which works great) and then simply added `@tensorflow/tfjs` to my dependencies:

```
$ npm install --save @tensorflow/tfjs
```

and added an import to `assembly/index.ts`:

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
```

[Full code here on Github](https://github.com/timfpark/tensorflow-assemblyscript)

This results in an error when I build it:

```
$ npm run asbuild

> test-assemblyscript@1.0.0 asbuild
> npm run asbuild:untouched && npm run asbuild:optimized


> test-assemblyscript@1.0.0 asbuild:untouched
> asc assembly/index.ts --target debug

ERROR TS6054: File '~lib/@tensorflow/tfjs.ts' not found.

 import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 in assembly/index.ts(1,21)

FAILURE 1 parse error(s)
```

Am I misunderstanding the import syntax?  I am puzzled why it would be looking in ~lib for this versus node_modules.

Comment: You can't import non-assemblyscript into AssemblyScript

Comment: Yes apparently AssemblyScript imports are done slightly different than the ESM standard. It's explained [here](https://www.assemblyscript.org/concepts.html#module-imports). However `tfjs` is not an AS file anyways so you can not import it before transpiling the whole thing into AS.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure the module you are trying to import is assemblyscript files, you can import with something like this `./node_modules/@tenderflow/tfjs`.

I am not sure if `@tensorflow` has assembly files built, but I did that on `assemblyscript-json` for `assemblyscript@0.19.8` (`0.25.2` doesn't have that problem).

### For example

`assemblyscript-json` has exported assemblyscript files from its package, so I can do this ([ref](https://github.com/near/assemblyscript-json/blob/main/assembly/JSON.ts))

```js
import { JSON } from './node_modules/assemblyscript-json/assembly';

export function formatJsonString(jsonString: string): string {
  const jsonObj: JSON.Obj = <JSON.Obj>JSON.parse(jsonString);
  return jsonObj.stringify();
}
```